# Excel Sumif Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel

Hi Want to do the follow

Have one sheet 'title with a colomn wise list of categoraties and associated SEARCH criteria as follows:

```
ONLINE Expenses        |  Food Expenses

AMAZON ICELAND*        |  ID 2

AMAZON USA*            |  ID 3
```

I have anothor sheet that list a bunch of expenses as follows

```
Amount        | Description            | 
100           | AMAZON ICELAND PLC 232 | 
4300          | sdsdsadsfd             |
```

I want to be able to sum all AMAZON expenses by using the SUMIF function and selecting all the criteria in colomn one of the look-up table.

Any ideas how to do this? or should I be looking at another function, not SUMIF?

Comment: Perhaps... `SUMIFS`?

Comment: What about `=SUMIF(Sheet2!B:B,"*AMAZON*",Sheet2!A:A)`? What do you mean by ***selecting all the criteria in colomn one of the look-up table.***?